# Different values of the same query in Opecart

Tags: php, mysql, opencart, php-7

I am using **Opencart 1.5** and I am working on localhost. In the product table, I have added three new columns which are:

```
`review_status` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
`lock_edit_view` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
`reviewed_by_admin` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
```

When I ran a query on DB from **PHPMyAdmin** its shows me the values:

**Query:**

```
SELECT product_id, review_status, reviewed_by_admin, lock_edit_view
FROM oc_product where product_id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

**Result:**

```
product_id   review_status      reviewed_by_admin   lock_edit_view  
    1               1                   1                   1
    2               1                   1                   1
    3               1                   1                   1
    4               1                   1                   1
```

But when I query on **Opencart** it showed me different values:

**Model Query:**

```
public function getProductsByProductIds($data = array())
{
    $sql = "SELECT product_id, review_status, reviewed_by_admin, lock_edit_view FROM oc_product where product_id IN (1,2,3,4)";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->rows;
}
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1
            [review_status] => 0
            [lock_edit_view] => 0
            [reviewed_by_admin] => 0
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 2
            [review_status] => 0
            [lock_edit_view] => 0
            [reviewed_by_admin] => 0
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 3
            [review_status] => 0
            [lock_edit_view] => 0
            [reviewed_by_admin] => 0
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 4
            [review_status] => 0
            [lock_edit_view] => 0
            [reviewed_by_admin] => 0
        )   
)
```

I don't know how it shows me different values of the same query.

Comment: You code working fine i have test myself, it return all value that i expected. so check step by step. like  "echo $sql" and that sql query execute in phpmyadmin and again check line by line weather required output or not